# Can not read XML document containing ampersand symbol

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a program that reads a XML file with Visual C#. I have a problem reading the Xml file, because it contains invalid XML symbols, for example '&'.

I have to read the XML but I can not modify the document. How can I modify the Xml file using C#? My code so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc;
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("nuevo.xml");


        XmlNodeList Xpersonas = doc.GetElementsByTagName("personas");
        XmlNodeList Xlista = ((XmlElement)Xpersonas[0]).GetElementsByTagName("edad");

            foreach (XmlElement nodo in Xlista)
            {
                string edad = nodo.GetAttribute("edad");
                string nombre = nodo.InnerText;
                textBox1.Text = nodo.InnerXml;
            }
```

Comment: You want to make the `XmlDocument` object accept an invalid Xml document? Can you post some of the Xml document that is invalid?

Comment: This is the XmlDocument  ->            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<personas>
<nombre>Pablo</nombre>
<edad>
34 & 34
</edad>
</personas>

Comment: Are you able to load the Xml file into memory and parse out any erroneous information? I.e. convert the ampersands (`&`) to the appropriate escape sequences?

Comment: I can only modify the document through Visual c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @EBrown suggested, one possibility would be read the file content in a string variable and replace the `&` symbol with the correct representation for propert XML `&amp;` and then parse the XML structure. A possible solution could look like this:

```
var xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(@"nuevo.xml");
XmlDocument doc;
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlContent.Replace("&", "&amp;"));

XmlNodeList Xpersonas = doc.GetElementsByTagName("personas");
XmlNodeList Xlista = ((XmlElement)Xpersonas[0]).GetElementsByTagName("edad");

foreach (XmlElement nodo in Xlista)
{
    string edad = nodo.GetAttribute("edad");
    string nombre = nodo.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(nodo.InnerXml.Replace("&amp;", "&"));
}
```

The output is:

```
34 & 34
```

If it is ok to use LINQ2XML, then the solution is even shorter, and there is no need to write the reverse(second) replace, because LINQ2XML make this for you automatically:

```
var xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(@"nuevo.xml");
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent.Replace("&", "&amp;"));
var edad = xmlDocument.Root.Element("edad").Value;
Console.WriteLine(edad);
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: As a purist I have to warn against the blanket replacements of ampersands (`&`) with the escape (`&amp`): who knows what ampersands in the XML are already escaped, or worse: escape something else.

Comment: Visual c# say me that 'File' don´t exit, What I do?

Comment: @EBrown: I agree. In such case the only solution would be probably a custom XML parser, which could be a tedious task to do.

Comment: @garci: I have updated the code in the answer according to your question.

Comment: It is a error in the program, and I can not run the program

Comment: Visual c# say me in 'File.', the name 'File' not exist in the actual context

Comment: @garci You should add a `using System.IO;` at the top of the `.cs` file. If you don't have a basic enough understanding of Visual Studio, C# or .NET to make this determination, I recommend you read some tutorials on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: As @420_Gone mentioned, you have to take care about signs already escaped and possible special chars like &nbsp;... it becomes $amp;nbsp; It's far from ideal.

Comment: @gramgram I agree. My answer offers a very basic and quick solution.